# Position of direct object of phrasal verb (bring up)

Tags: verbs

Is it grammatically correct if I say:

> His mother brought that little matter of his prison record up again.

Or should I better say:

> His mother brought that little matter up of his prison record again.

I know it is the correct to say:

> His mother brought up that little matter of his prison record again.

However, I am not sure about the other option.

Comment: Both of them sound fine to me. But as the noun phrase is too long, I wouldn't use the first sentence. It's only my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The further the preposition is from the verb, the more difficult the understanding. While all sentences are technically correct, (You are allowed to separate 'brought' from 'up.') it's a good idea to keep them together. The exception would be when a pronoun is the direct object. Then, you want to put the object between the verb and the preposition: 'Why even bring it up?'